# Saving strings in quotes (") using regex

Tags: php, regex

I've got a simple string that looks like `a:104:{i:143;a:5:{s:5:"naz";s:7:"Alb";s:10:"base"}}` and I'd like to save all text in quotation mark cleaning it of things like `s:5` and stuff using regex. Is this possible?

Comment: Although I think I get what you mean, for clarity can you post what the Expected Output would be?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: What would the desired output be for the example you posted?  It is a little unclear.

Comment: Well all ive maneged to clean it of all letters and some soecial chars like echo preg_replace('/[0-9a-zA-Z^\;^\:]/',"",$data); Autpoy shold be clean json so {{"naz":"alb"}}

Comment: 1.  Specify what output you want.   2.  Show what code you have currently and explain how it isn't doing what you want.

Comment: Is this a serialized or session-encoded string?

Answer (score 1):

Want to get everything between quotes? use: `".*"` as your search string (escape `"` characters as required)

..also you can check out http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm for more help with regex. (It's got a great tool where you can test input text, RE, and see what you get out)

Answer (score 0):

As long as the double quotes are matched, the following call

```
preg_match_all('/"([^"]*)"/',$input_string,$matches);
```

will give you all the text between the quotes as array of strings in `$matches[1]`

Answer (score 0):

```
function session_raw_decode ($data) {
    $vars = preg_split('/([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff^|]*)\|/', $data, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    $result = array();
    for($i = 0; isset($vars[$i]); $i++)
        $result[$vars[$i++]] = unserialize($vars[$i]);
    return $result;
}
```

I have this snippet somewhere found on my server... (no idea from where it is or if I have it written myself)

You can use it and do:

```
$json = json_encode(session_raw_decode($string));
```

This should do the job.